# post-update to ssh remote live server and pull master branch problem

Tags: git, ssh, push, live

I have a situation where for size limitations, I can't host the bare repository on the same server as a particular website.  So I've setup a bare repository on server A which I want to push the master branch too when happy that the update is good.
In the hooks/post-update it should ssh to the live server and pull the master branch.

I've generated a public ssh key on the live server, authorized it and copied the public key into /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the bare repo server.  Bascially done everything on this site [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/)

But it's failing when attempting to authenticate to the live server.

The post-update looks like this :

```
ssh liveuser@liveserver.com

cd cd/path/to/site/.git || exit
git pull bare master
exit
```

I get this message

```
$ git push server master
userForBare@www.ServerAAddress.com's password:
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 3 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 279 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: *** Pulling changes into Live [Live's post-update hook] ***
remote:
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
remote: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
To ssh://userForBare@www.ServerAAddress.com/var/git/websiteToUpdate.git
   b251909..883d129  master -> master
```

Comment: You confuse the "live" and "A" servers a bit. Also you don't log in as `www` user anywhere, so why do you mention `/var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys` (storing anything ssh-related inside document root is probably bad idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to run `git pull` on `live`, which means the `live` will ssh back into `www.ServerAAddress.com`. So there are 2 sshs that need to use passphrase-less public key for authentication and one of them is not correctly authorized:

1. ssh from "A" ("bare") to "live" needs private key (`.ssh/id*`) stored on "A" and public key (in `.ssh/authorized_keys`) on "live".
2. ssh from "live" back to "A" (inside the `git pull`) needs private key stored on "live" and public key on "A". The keys should be different.

The locations on the servers are probably different. The files on "A" need to be in `userForBare`'s home, while files on "live" need to be in home of `www` user.

Look in the logs (ssh usually logs into `/var/log/auth` or `/var/log/security`) and check that it's actually finding the public keys it's supposed to *and* that it's willing to read it:

- Many setups will *not* have `/var/www` as `$HOME` of the `www` user, so you may need to place the `.ssh/authorized_keys` elsewhere.
- ssh refuses to read anything `$HOME/.ssh/` if the file or any directory up to root is writable by anybody except that user or root, so if e.g. `/var/www` is group-writable, ssh will reject `/var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys` as possibly compromised.